# Transfer columns into rows in sql server management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

**Table 1**

```
column_pk  num  name   id -1   id-2     id-3
1          145  sam    12345   null     34527
2          187  tom    null    76544    null
3          567  david  78965   43215    89765
4          675  john   null    null     null
```

As shown in above table for a given column_pk id-1, id-2, id-3 can have values or they can be null

Now I have to move `id-1`, i`d-2`, `id-3` into `Table2` rows as follows:

- Since Sam has 2 id’s: `id-1` & `id-3` for the same num 145 Sam has 2 rows
- Since David has 3 id’s in `Table 1`, `Table 2` has 3 rows for David for the same num 567

**Table 2**

```
Column_pk  num    name     id
1          145    sam      12345
2          145    sam      34527
3          187    tom      76544
4          567    david    78965
5          567    david    43215          
6          567    david    89765
```

- I tried using few update statements, but those statements are useful for limited data only. Can you please help me with this when where there is huge transfer of data.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, you can *unpivot* the data using `CROSS APPLY` and `VALUES`. This process takes your column values and converts them into rows:

```
select row_number() over(order by t1.column_pk) column_pk,
  t1.num, 
  t1.name, 
  c.value
from table1 t1
cross apply
(
  values 
    ('id1', id1),
    ('id2', id2),
    ('id3', id3)
) c (col, value)
where c.value is not null;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d36b6/4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` to combine the results.  Then use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get your new pk column:

```
select Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY column_pk,sortorder) Column_pk, 
  num, name, id
from
  (
    select column_pk, num, name, id1 id, 1 sortorder
    from yourtable
    union 
    select column_pk, num, name, id2, 2 sortorder
    from yourtable
    union 
    select column_pk, num, name, id3, 3 sortorder
    from yourtable
    ) t
where id is not null
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/152e0/1)